# use id, not label, for a DSpaceControlledVocabulary

Tags: dspace

In my DSpace installation, I have a controlled vocabulary. It is similar to the example `srsc.xml` controlled vocabulary from the original Dspace distribution.

I noticed that for `DSpaceControlledVocabulary`/ (.xml file-based) controlled vocabularies, DSpace assigns to the metadata key (e.g. *dc.subject*) the value of the controlled vocabulary entry's *label* value.

Instead of the label value, I would rather prefer to assign the *id* value, that is:
Instead of `dc.subject=Research Subject Categories::HUMANITIES and RELIGION::Religion/Theology::Church studies` I would rather like to transmit `dc.subject=VR110103`.

Is this possible to configure?

Comment: The following document might help: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Configuration+Reference#ConfigurationReference-ControlledVocabularySettings  If you do not get a helpful response here, try the dspace-tech mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

This is not so difficult. In the file vocabulary-support.js you need to change the line `link.setAttribute('href', data.value);` (https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/scripts/vocabulary-support.js#L181) to `link.setAttribute('href', data.id);`

This will insert the id into the metadata field instead of the value.

If you are using a DSpace release version, you have to put the modified file under dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage2/scripts/vocabulary-support.js (assuming you are using Mirage 2).